# Limiting access to hyperlinks based on if a 'company' has bought a service.

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

Background Info: I am making a login application in ASP.NET. I have created 2 roles an admin role, and student role. When guests register they are assigned to a one of these role. The students are then assigned to companies. I currently have a companies table and a 'LINKS' table. The links table would just hold a few hyperlinks to different projects.I want to be able to allow access to companies and their students if they have purchased one the 'links' from the links table. I have attached a database diagram to this. Please help! I think I am just missing a bool assigned value... Also, i'm not sure how to route the data... either.

What I want to do:

I am trying to have limited access for users. Lets say A company called waterworks has 6 employees... The company... waterworks paid for 3 "links" out of 10. I want the company waterworks  and its employees/students which has 6 employees to be able to access the 3 links they paid for. On a side note... these links would be a hyperlink to another website which has power points etc... these other websites have to be paid for access. so i need only certain links to be viewed by certain companies.

[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6tXD.jpg)

Comment: From your description (which was not very clear to begin with) and your database diagram, it seems that you are missing an intermediate table for your many-to-many relationship between links and companies

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear, if you have a link can be purchased by more than one company then in order to make this relationship on a database level you need something like this:

[image]

The intermediate table will hold the PKs of the other two tables

Comment: okay gotcha, that makes sense. how would I assign or unassign companies to these links?

Comment: adding and removing entries in the intermediate table

Comment: this didnt solve my problem. instead I created roles for each of the links... and assigned users to roles.

Comment: i am pretty sure that we could achieve that using my approach. In case case, im glad you resolved your issue.

Comment: Another thing, using the intermediate table approach you could add more functionality like "valid until" lets say that will automatically suspend the subscription of the company if the time has passed. With the roles approach you will have to go and remove the role.

Comment: your approach makes sense, im just not sure how to do it using syntax. i'm really new to the asp.net mvc design pattern. and not great at c# or javascript yet... so its difficult to do custom things :\

Comment: Sorry to ask but why you did not choose a framework that you are comfortable with?

Comment: this is the only framework I have experience in. Im really new to it all haha, i went to a coding bootcamp for 3 months... got a job and now trying to figure things out... i do have some computer science background knowledge... but its not deep.

Comment: for what is worth, i think you got the whole concept wrong in the above project (sorry :()

Comment: Your database design is not something that is going to help you...especially not in the long term.

Comment: why would it not help me? and what would help me??

Comment: Send me your updated database design and i will tell you the problems i see

Comment: do you mean the database diagram? or do you want the models that were used to create the tables?